# Java How to get Value from Optional Dialog Box

Tags: java, dialog, option-type

JAVA How to get Value from Optional Dialogue BOX

HELLO,
i need help since am stack =D with this problem i made little program and now i made little option dialoge box with few options i want to save option u choose as Int how could i do that and here is the code:

```
final JButton btnOdaberi = new JButton("Odaberi");
        btnOdaberi.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int t = 0;
                String[] rate = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"};
             int izaberi = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(btnOdaberi, "Izaberi broj rata", "Rate",0,t,null, rate,"1");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reword the question, I'm very confused.... -_- ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already save it in izaberi variable, all you need to do is to display it.
try:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your choice was: "+(izaberi+1));
```

below your int izaberi...

Comment: To put it in a more general way, `izaberi` is the index of the element of the `rate` array that has been selected.